# sql <> not working with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I Have a simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM SlabRateDetail 
WHERE Fromdate <> '01/04/2010 12:00:00 AM'
```

but when I run this query I see `01/04/2010 12:00:00 AM` in my results.

Any Idea why? I have even tried using `!=`

Comment: Does your saved time contain milliseconds? Do you really want to exclude a single second of time from your query?

Comment: What datatype is the `fromdate` column ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Its DATETIME

Comment: `<>` and `!=` are the same things. The only difference is `<>` is ANSI STANDARD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use unambiguous ISO8601  like dates when specifying date literals (`YYYY/MM/DD`)

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM SlabRateDetail 
WHERE Fromdate <> '2010-04-01 12:00:00 AM'
```

I believe you are seeing dates that are `2010/01/04`

By default SQL Server uses the US date convention of `MM/DD/YYYY` for literals (depending on your server settings)

Comment: Whether that is unambiguous or not depends on whether the OP is using `datetime`  or `date`/`datetime2`. The following returns two different dates. `SET LANGUAGE ITALIAN;SELECT CAST('2010-04-01 12:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME);SELECT CAST('2010-04-01 12:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME2)`

Comment: Then I'd say that was a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM SlabRateDetail WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Fromdate, 106) <> CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '01/04/2010 12:00:00 AM', 106)
```